# Aligning dynamic inputs neatly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a form recently that can add, duplicate and remove a row of inputs dynamically. But aligning them hasn't been so easy.

Here is an illustration of the problem.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1"><input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input2"><input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input3"><input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate"><input type="button" class="remove" value="remove"><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#add {
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line').clone();

    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('form').append(blank_line.clone());
        $('.input_line').last().before($(this));
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $('.input_line').last().before($('#add'));
        input = input - 1;
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
       $(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone());
       $('.input_line').last().before($('#add'));
       input = input + 1;
    });
});
```

What would be the easiest approach to this?
Any help would be appreciated!

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/23z60s1q/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same code structure, add below class in your CSS,

```
.input_line {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Here is the Updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/23z60s1q/2/

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm a little shocked how easy that was haha, when you add margin-left why isn't it causing a gap between the row and the 'add field' button?

Comment: because you have already provided "float:left" to "add field" button, which makes the element floating and will not be impacted by the div, which are "static" element by default.

Comment: if my answer helped you I would request you to select it! and an Upvote would be a kind gesture of appreciation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Position the button absolutely:

```
#add {
    left: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

form {
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tLqv003/

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you have changed to cause this, but when you click 'add field' it adds a bunch of new rows?

Comment: I'm sorry I mixed the comment up with the other guys response, read my commend again.

Comment: It's just because of the way your function is written and the fact that I manually added rows at the beginning. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/5tLqv003/1/

Comment: Ohh, now I see why, the proof of concept rows and being duplicated by the jQuery. Is this the most efficient way of aligning them?